# Self-adjointness of $D=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}-1$ with boundary conditions $u'(0) = 0 = u'(a)$ on $[0,a]$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory

Im trying to show that $$D=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}-1$$ is self adjoint on $[0,a]$ subject to $u'(0)=u'(a)=0$. I think I need to use integration by parts but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: What inner product are you using?

Comment: What is the source of the problem?

Comment: Please do not make your question unintelligible after you received an answer.

Comment: Alex's reply to Jp McCarthy was also deleted.  I think it said something like $(u,v)=\int_0^a\overline{u(x)}v(x)dx$.

Comment: @Alex: You are no longer wondering about how to find the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of $D$?

Comment: @JonasMeyer: I was able to figure that out.  I can post what I came up with in a little bit.

Comment: Also, sorry to everyone regarding the question editing--I left my computer open and a friend started messing with things.

Answer (score 3):

Show that $D$ is self-adjoint is equivalent to showing the integral identity
$$ \int_0^a \left( \frac{d^2 \bar{u}}{dx^2} - \bar{u} \right) v \, dx = \int_0^a \bar{u} \left( \frac{d^2 v}{dx^2} - v \right) \, dx$$
when both $u,v$ have derivatives vanishing at $x= 0,a$. As you yourself suggested, you should be able to show this using integration by parts, since the whole purpose of integration by parts is to move a derivative from one function to another. Notice that you don't want to do integration by parts on the whole integral as it is written above, since the term $\int_0^a - \bar{u} v \, dx$ already matches on both sides of the equation.